# Add an Index to a list that resets depending on Id group

Tags: c#, linq

Given an object such as:

```
public class Test
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public int Field1 { get; set; }
   public int Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Which is populated like this:

```
List<Test> list = new List<Test>();
list.Add( new Test { Id = 1, field1 = 1});
list.Add( new Test { Id = 1, field1 = 2});
list.Add( new Test { Id = 2, field1 = 3});
list.Add( new Test { Id = 2, field1 = 4});
```

I can create an index column and iterate through the list:

```
var indexList = list.Select((t, i) => new {t, index = i}).ToList();

foreach (var t in indexList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: " + t.t.Id + " ---- Index:" + t.index);
}
```

And I get results like this:

```
ID: 1 ---- Index:0
ID: 1 ---- Index:1
ID: 2 ---- Index:2
ID: 2 ---- Index:3
```

What I really want to do is reset the index for each Id group so that I get output like this:

```
ID: 1 ---- Index:0
ID: 1 ---- Index:1
ID: 2 ---- Index:0
ID: 2 ---- Index:1
```

I've tried playing with GroupBy without much luck.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

Comment: Are you opposed to using a `Dictionary<int, List<TestFields>>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
var indexList = list
    .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp
        .Select((item, index) => new { index = index, t = item }))
    .ToList();
```

**Example:**  http://ideone.com/nSTa8A

Comment: Anyone care to comment on the downvote? Something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
var indexList = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Id)
                    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((t, i) => new {t, index = i})
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Bunny yes I have to make selection on each group